# VBA to copy one worksheet to multiple other worksheets in MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, data-conversion

I am looking to copy an existing (already created worksheet) into about 500 workbooks (*.xlsx) that all reside in the same folder. Another user (@tigeravatar) was able to [generate the below code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166025/vba-to-copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-all-workbooks-in-another-folder) that could be utilized in MS Excel but they asked me to open up another question since I didnt clarify my desire to use it in MS Access.

My rudimentary knowledge of VBA tells me I need to to do something like 'Dim ObjXL As Object`and then`Set ObjXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application") but beyond that I am unsure how to proceed.

Simply need the above code converted so that it can utilized in MS Access as it works perfectly in MS Excel

```
Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Set wsCopy = wbMaster.Worksheets("Babelfish")

    Dim sFolderPath As String
    sFolderPath = wbMaster.Path & "\PLOGs\"
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"

    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*.xlsx")

    'Disable screenupdating (to prevent "screen flickering" so macro runs smoother)
    'Disable alerts (to suppress "Are you sure?" prompts during worksheet deletion)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Begin loop through files in the folder
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0

        Dim sWBOpenPassword As String
        Dim sWBProtectPassword As String
        Select Case sFileName
            'Specify workbook names that require passwords here
            Case "Book2.xlsx", "Another Protected File.xlsx", "Third generic password file.xlsx"
                sWBOpenPassword = "password"
                sWBProtectPassword = "secondpassword"

            'If different books require different passwords, can specify additional names with their unique passwords
            Case "Book3.xlsx"
                sWBOpenPassword = "book3openpassword"
                sWBProtectPassword = "book3protectionpassword"

            'Keep specifying excel file names and their passwords until completed
            Case "Book10.xlsx", "Book257.xlsx"
                sWBOpenPassword = "GenericOpenPW2"
                sWBProtectPassword = "GenericProtectPW2"

            'etc...


            'Case Else will handle the remaining workbooks that don't require passwords
            Case Else
                sWBOpenPassword = ""
                sWBProtectPassword = ""

        End Select

        'Open file using password (if any)
        With Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName, , , , Password:=sWBOpenPassword)

            Dim bProtectedWB As Boolean
            bProtectedWB = False    'Reset protected wb check to false

            'Check if workbook is protected and if so unprotect it using the specified protection password
            If .ProtectStructure = True Then bProtectedWB = True
            If bProtectedWB = True Then .Unprotect sWBProtectPassword

            On Error Resume Next    'Suppress error if copied worksheet does not yet exist
            .Worksheets(wsCopy.Name).Delete 'Delete existing sheet if it exists
            On Error GoTo 0         'Remove "On Error Resume Next" condition


            wsCopy.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)   'Copy template into the workbook
            .Worksheets(wsCopy.Name).Cells.Replace wbMaster.Name, .Name 'Change references from master workbook to current workbook

            'If workbook was protected, reprotect it with same protection password
            If bProtectedWB = True Then .Protect sWBProtectPassword

            'Close file and save the changes
            .Close True
        End With

        sFileName = Dir 'Advance to next file in the folder
    Loop

    'Re-enable screenupdating and alerts
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I desire the same end result as the other thread (to copy one worksheet into multiple other worksheets) but just need it to work in MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by making sure you have added the reference to the Excel Object Library (I'm on 365 so mine is currently 16.0) 
[image: References]

then the following adjustments to your code will work... basically defining that xl is an excel application and then preceding workbook calls with xl.

```
Sub Command0_Click()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wbMaster As Excel.Workbook
Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set wbMaster = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\OrWhateverYourPathAndFileNameIs.xlsx")

Dim wsCopy As Excel.Worksheet
Set wsCopy = wbMaster.Worksheets("Babelfish")

Dim sFolderPath As String
sFolderPath = wbMaster.Path & "\PLOGs\"
If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"

Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*.xlsx")

'Disable screenupdating (to prevent "screen flickering" so macro runs smoother)
'Disable alerts (to suppress "Are you sure?" prompts during worksheet deletion)
xl.ScreenUpdating = False
xl.DisplayAlerts = False

'Begin loop through files in the folder
Do While Len(sFileName) > 0

    Dim sWBOpenPassword As String
    Dim sWBProtectPassword As String
    Select Case sFileName
        'Specify workbook names that require passwords here
        Case "Book2.xlsx", "Another Protected File.xlsx", "Third generic password file.xlsx"
            sWBOpenPassword = "password"
            sWBProtectPassword = "secondpassword"

        'If different books require different passwords, can specify additional names with their unique passwords
        Case "Book3.xlsx"
            sWBOpenPassword = "book3openpassword"
            sWBProtectPassword = "book3protectionpassword"

        'Keep specifying excel file names and their passwords until completed
        Case "Book10.xlsx", "Book257.xlsx"
            sWBOpenPassword = "GenericOpenPW2"
            sWBProtectPassword = "GenericProtectPW2"

        'etc...


        'Case Else will handle the remaining workbooks that don't require passwords
        Case Else
            sWBOpenPassword = ""
            sWBProtectPassword = ""

    End Select

    'Open file using password (if any)
    With xl.Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName, , , , Password:=sWBOpenPassword)

        Dim bProtectedWB As Boolean
        bProtectedWB = False    'Reset protected wb check to false

        'Check if workbook is protected and if so unprotect it using the specified protection password
        If .ProtectStructure = True Then bProtectedWB = True
        If bProtectedWB = True Then .Unprotect sWBProtectPassword

        On Error Resume Next    'Suppress error if copied worksheet does not yet exist
        .Worksheets(wsCopy.Name).Delete 'Delete existing sheet if it exists
        On Error GoTo 0         'Remove "On Error Resume Next" condition


        wsCopy.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)   'Copy template into the workbook
        .Worksheets(wsCopy.Name).Cells.Replace wbMaster.Name, .Name 'Change references from master workbook to current workbook

        'If workbook was protected, reprotect it with same protection password
        If bProtectedWB = True Then .Protect sWBProtectPassword

        'Close file and save the changes
        .Close True
    End With

    sFileName = Dir 'Advance to next file in the folder
Loop

'Re-enable screenupdating and alerts
xl.ScreenUpdating = True
xl.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! I figured it was something as simple as defining 'Dim xl As Excel.Application`